# HttpClient - WebException: A conexão subjacente estava fechada: A conexão foi fechada de modo inesperado

Tags: c#, json, api, http-request

criei uma aplicação C# console muito simples para testar conexão numa API, mas não consigo enviar o request. Tentei com outras API e funcionaram, mas esta específica não consigo. Seria uma consulta na API do CartolaFC (está comentada no código abaixo, a outra funciona).

Segue código: erro gerado:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleAppHttp
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync();
        }

        static void RunAsync()
        {
            using (var clientAPI = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Um dos sites recomendava isso pra corrigir o problema, mas ainda não funciona
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

                clientAPI.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //string sResponse = clientAPI.GetStringAsync("http://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status").Result; //Não Funciona
                string sResponse = clientAPI.GetStringAsync("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").Result; //Funciona

                Console.Write(sResponse);
            }

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Segue erro gerado:

```
System.AggregateException ocorrido
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Um ou mais erros.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean 
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean 
waitCompletionNotification)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   em ConsoleAppHttp.Program.RunAsync() em e:\ricardo\documents\visual 
studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleAppHttp\ConsoleAppHttp\Program.cs:linha 32
   em ConsoleAppHttp.Program.Main(String[] args) em 
e:\ricardo\documents\visual studio 
2017\Projects\ConsoleAppHttp\ConsoleAppHttp\Program.cs:linha 21

Exceção interna 1:
HttpRequestException: Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a solicitação.

Exceção interna 2:
WebException: A conexão subjacente estava fechada: A conexão foi fechada de modo inesperado.
```

Alguém teria ideia de como posso resolver? Conseguem reproduzir o problema?

Obs.: Usando VS Community 2017, Windows 10 atualizado.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar ao menos um `User-Agent`

```
clientAPI.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Mozilla", "5.0"));
```

Veja o código final

```
static void RunAsync()
{
    using (var clientAPI = new HttpClient())
    {               
        clientAPI.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        clientAPI.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Mozilla", "5.0"));
        string sResponse = clientAPI.GetStringAsync("http://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status").Result;

        Console.Write(sResponse);
    }

    Console.Read();

}
```

Comment: Sim, obrigado. Logo depois que postei aqui, responderam em outro fórum, a mesma resposta. Já testei e funcionou. Estou começando a mexer com essas conexões, sou programador das antigas, estava muito tempo sem programar e comecei a "brincar" de novo. Aproveitando, por que para uma API foi necessário e outra não? Como posso descobrir essa necessidade?

Comment: Eu não sei te dizer o certo, mas eu já fiz alguns webcrawlers e já passei por isso, então, antes de te responder eu fiz um teste indo até o navegador e fiz uma chamada get, ou seja, copie e colei na barra de endereço e dei enter, e vi que funcionou, com isso só podia estar faltando algum parametro na sua chamada e pela experiencia setei apenas o UserAgent e funcionou, poderia não ter funcionado, ai nesta situação eu iria adicionando outros paramentros até que desse certo.

Comment: Sim, foi o que pensei, tinha tentado outros parâmetros, mas não o User-Agent.